# How to call custom function in AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to call `$scope function` in `AngularJS Directive` in following way

`JS`

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('customDirEx', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        {
            name: 'ABC',
            rno: '100'
        },
        {
            name: 'DEF',
            rno: '200'
        }
    ];

    $scope.onChangeFoo = function() {
        console.log('test');
    }

    $scope.dataChange = function() {
        console.log('test abc', $scope);
        $scope.onInitEle();
    }

    $scope.dataChange();
}]);

app.directive('studentInfo', function(){
    var directive = {};

    directive.scope = {
        user: '=user',
        onInitEle: '='
    };
    directive.restrict = 'EA';
    directive.template = '<div>Name: {{user.name}}<br>R.NO: {{user.rno}}</div>';

    return directive;
});
```

`HTML`

```
<body ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="customDirEx">            
            <student-info ng-repeat="user in users" user="user" on-init-ele="onChangeFoo"></student-info>            
        </div>
    </body>
```

`$scope.onInitEle is not a function` - this is the error I'm getting

The purpose of calling `onClickEle` instead of `onChangeFoo` here is too reuse the `JS` at multiple places so that I can call `onChangeBar` when required.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047489/how-to-define-a-function-inside-angular-js-directive

Comment: You have to pass a function with `'&'`, not `'='`.

Comment: @Zooly Before posting question I tried that too but no use

Comment: Please see this answer, it should perfectly match with your need https://stackoverflow.com/a/18378602/4781975

Comment: Why `$scope.dataChange` call `$scope.onClickEle` function ? I guest it should be `$scope.onChangeFoo` @Mahesh.D

Comment: @Zooly I'm looking from two way binding, so went with '=' instead of '&'. I've seen somewhere we can use '=' in this case.

Comment: I think two way databinding is for var/object only. Why function should be twoway ?

Comment: What version of angular do you use ?

Comment: @Korte AngularJS v1.6.7

Comment: You should be using [angularjs components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) instead of a directive. It has way more handy api for what you try to achieve.

Comment: @Korte It helped

Answer (score 1):

First you have to replace `"onClickEle: '='"` with `"onClickEle: '&'"`
The use of & means you are passing reference.

The second mistake is you didn't call it from your template. So, I have changed your template code as:

```
directive.template = '<div ng-click="onClickEle()"> Name: {{user.name}}<br>R.NO: {{user.rno}}</div>';
```

The third mistake is: you are calling `$scope.onClickEle();` in controller, however onClickEle() not defined in controller, its under directive. So, controller unable to find the method.

The forth mistake is you are passing `on-click-ele="onChangeFoo"` in the direcive, the correct syntax  will be:

```
on-click-ele="onChangeFoo()"
```

The working updated code given below:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('customDirEx', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        {
            name: 'ABC',
            rno: '100'
        },
        {
            name: 'DEF',
            rno: '200'
        }
    ];

    $scope.onChangeFoo = function() {
        console.log('test....');
    }

    $scope.dataChange = function() {
        console.log('test abc', $scope);
        //$scope.onClickEle();
    }

    $scope.dataChange();
}]);

app.directive('studentInfo', function(){
    var directive = {};

    directive.scope = {
        user: '=user',
        onClickEle: '&'
    };
    directive.restrict = 'EA';
    directive.template = '<div ng-click="onClickEle()"> Name: {{user.name}}<br>R.NO: {{user.rno}}</div>';

    return directive;
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="customDirEx">            
            <student-info ng-repeat="user in users" user="user" on-click-ele="onChangeFoo()"></student-info>            
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Ahmed thanks for your efforts but it doesn't fulfill my requirements. I think you had confused with 'onClickEle()', sorry for that. I had replaced 'onClickEle()' with 'onInitEle()', I think it makes sense now.

Comment: @Mahesh.D, you cannot call directive function from controller. Directive can call the controller function, if you pass using & attribute, its point number 3.

Comment: @Ahmed if possible can you check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I can manage this by creating separate `controller` for directive but don't know the theory behind, it would be very helpful if someone explains clearly.

`JS`

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('customDirEx', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        {
            name: 'ABC',
            rno: '100'
        },
        {
            name: 'DEF',
            rno: '200'
        }
    ];

    $scope.onChangeFoo = function() {
        console.log('test');
    }        
}]);

app.controller('StudentCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.onInitEle();    
}]);

app.directive('studentInfo', function(){
    var directive = {};

    directive.scope = {
        user: '=user',
        onInitEle: '='
    };
    directive.restrict = 'EA';
    directive.template = '<div>Name: {{user.name}}<br>R.NO: {{user.rno}}</div>';
    directive.controller = 'StudentCtrl';

    return directive;
});
```

`HTML`

```
<body ng-app="app">
     <div ng-controller="customDirEx">            
            <student-info ng-repeat="user in users" user="user" on-init-ele="onChangeFoo"></student-info>            
     </div>
</body>
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rh7e575w/5/)